# Isotope filtering with CSS transitions - fade only

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm trying to deactivate the css transitions of the height and width of items when filtered out using isotope. So, just having items fade out or in, and move about - no scaling.

I've tried all kinds of css modification to the standard css transitions: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html#css_transitions , but no success.

Is this possible without modifications to the plugin?

Here's a demo of what I have at the moment: http://codepen.io/2kp/pen/nAGkp

Comment: have you tried css opacity?

Comment: The default css transition options include css opacity and scale which both work. I'm just trying to remove the scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#container').isotope({
      hiddenStyle: {
        opacity: 0
      },
      visibleStyle: {
        opacity: 1
      }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking the route of modifying the plugin itself (by removing `transform:"scale(0.001)"` and `transform:"scale(1)"`) since overriding the hiddenStyle and visibleStyle objects wasn't working (as suggested by the Isotope documentation http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#visiblestyle).

Hope that helps! Seems like a bug in the plugin.

Comment: Are you using isotope v2 with hiddenStyle and visibleStyle? It works for me.

Comment: Maybe I didn't see this in the documentation, or it was a bug which is fixed, but the hiddenStyle and visibleStyle edits work fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to do something similar, animating only opacity + height, not the width and think on my way I found a solution that works for you - at least I hope so!

Just add this to your JS:

```
$('#container').isotope({
    // options...
    transformsEnabled: false
});
```

and change CSS to:

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
       -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
          transition-property: top, left, opacity;
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. You still get some scaling weirdness.