# Is it possible to use Isotope filtering without using an Isotope layout mode / transforming the layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, jquery-isotope, masonry

I've been looking all over but can't seem to figure out if this is possible. I have a layout on which I would like to use Isotope's filtering feature, but at the same time I don't want to transform the position of the items. In other words, I don't want to use any of Isotope's layout modes. I'm hoping to use "position: relative" on the individual divs but Isotope overrides that.

Ideally, I'm thinking it would be great if the divs could just flow as they would without Isotope being involved, but Isotope's filtering could do something like just change the opacity of the divs. For example, clicking on "Dog" keeps all the .dog divs at 100% opacity and sets .cat and .squirrel to 0% opacity. Would something like this be possible??

In my search I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367231/isotope-filtering-with-css-transitions-fade-only) which gave me hope by introducing me to "[transformsEnabled: false](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/options.html#transformsenabled)" but I don't think it's quite what I need:

```
$('#container').isotope({
    // options...
    transformsEnabled: false
});
```

With transformsEnabled set to false, my layout works as I would hope in the default state, but it also prevents the Isotope filtering from happening…

Any suggestions? Am I hoping for the impossible? Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Sounds like you might not need isotope at all. Why not hook a simple click handler that toggles visibility of a set of items?

Comment: Hi @Radu thanks for the suggestion. I know it seems silly… The short answer is that I'm already using Isotope throughout the site (and more importantly, I'm still learning coding so I'm really inexperienced in Jquery…) The longer answer is, the site has a variety of different templates which are loaded randomly each visit. I already have the Isotope filtering (and occasionally layout modes) working in other templates so I was hoping to get it to work in this instance.

Comment: For those who still looking for the answer: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/675#issuecomment-40675160